# firebase get User UID using phone number

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to get User UID of any user just using phone number

[image]

if not how can i get user UID just by typing the phone number i mean search on the entire database for specific phone number and if it exist i get the ID

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need the Firebase [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuserbyphonenumber).

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber("+213666666666")
     .then((userRecord) => console.log(userRecord))
     .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can manage to get the user ID by using firebase auth. You can check this [official document for how to manage users in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

Comment: sorry but this options is for current user but i'm looking for method to get any user id just by knowing his phone number

Comment: After getting the user try getcurrentuser().getuid();